# Recoding variables inside a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe called perceptionAvailInfo which has multiple columns like below ->

```
nameslist<-names(perceptionAvailInfo)
nameslist
##  [1] "email"          "HomeAddress"    "HomePhone"      "Cellphone"     
##  [5] "Employer"       "PoliticalAffln" "WrittenWorks"   "Photo"         
##  [9] "Video"          "Groups"         "Birthdate"      "sex"           
## [13] "age"            "employ"         "sexLabel"       "age_group"
```

Each of these columns(eg: email) contains coded entries as 1,2,3,8,9 which I hope to recode into "Yes" , "No" etc.

I am trying to use something like the code below to get this done but I am not seeing the result I need->

```
for (k in nameslist) {
   if (perceptionAvailInfo[[k]] == 1) perceptionAvailInfo[[k]] <-"Yes"
}
```

Whats the correct syntax to replace all values of k with value 1 with "Yes" ?

Comment: can you please add your data in your question. use `dput(perceptionAvailInfo)` and add the output

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you are using a list in a way that is making life harder for you.  If you could dput that object, though, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

do this you are subsetting wrong

```
for(k in nameslist)
    {
      perceptionAvailInfo[k][perceptionAvailInfo[k]==1]<-"Yes"
    }
```

you don't need a `if` condition here

Answer (score 1):

We could use `recode` from `library(car)`.  We loop through the columns (`lapply(...`) and `recode` the 1 value to 'Yes' and the rest to 'No'.

```
library(car)
perceptionAvailInfo[] <- lapply(perceptionAvailInfo, recode, "1='Yes';else='No'")
```